# how can I add html-loader to angular for ng test?

Tags: angular

I currently have in my tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./types"
    "types": []
  },
```

And in my types/index.d.ts, I have:

```
declare module '*.html' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

And doing this allowed me to have my .ts files do:

```
import template from './template.html'
...
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: template
  ...
```

And everything in the real world works fine...  However, when I run `ng test` I am getting:

```
./app/javascript/components/my_component/template.html:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <tr *ngFor="let x of y">...</tr>
```

I am assuming this means I need `html-loader` in my webpack spec environment?  How can I add that via the angular.json file?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to modify angular.json:

```
       "architect": {
         "test": {
-          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
+          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
           "options": {
+            "customWebpackConfig": {
+              "path": "config/webpack/angular-webpack.config.js"
+            },
```

and then config/webpack/angular-webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```